# Display Recycler View without Navigation Layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm following a slidenerd youtubers tutorial on how to create a Recycler view but the series on Material Design starts with a Navigation Layout series. How can I display the Recycler view without what he's doing, as I'm unsure.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container
              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.hisdrawerid, container, false);
     recyclerView= (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.RViewId);
     return layout;
  }
```

He defines recyclerView above the onCreate as private RecyclerView recyclerView;

*EDIT* Here is the activity code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Lines extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lines);

    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.line_list);

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_item, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int i = item.getItemId();
    switch (i) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            Intent s = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
            startActivity(s);
            return true;

        case R.id.action_add:
            Intent a = new Intent(this, AddLine.class);
            startActivity(a);
            return true;


        case R.id.action_wheel:
            Intent w = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
            startActivity(w);
            return true;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Here is the .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Lines">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="LINES"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/line_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What are you asking, exactly? Are you asking how to not use `Fragment`s?

Comment: Looks fine to me... Though you aren't loading data into the view, so you'll see a blank page.

Comment: Generally speaking, you put a RecyclerView in the MainActivity content view... Then you findViewById, etc. and set the adapter to load in data.

Comment: I watched the tutorials all the way through a little while ago and I think he puts code in this section. I guess my question is can I just, can I exclude this code?

Comment: I'm adding this inside a linear layout because I have an action bar so it isn't the main content view. @cricket_007

Comment: This code is in a `Fragment`, apparently. Yes, you can do it without `Fragment`s, if you don't want to mess with them atm. Just get rid of the `Fragment` stuff, and setup the `RecyclerView` directly in your `Activity`. That said, if the method you've posted is in an `Activity` currently, you don't want that there.

Comment: Please post all relevant layout files as a [mcve]. My general idea still applies, regardless of where you put the RecyclerView. The NavigationView can entirely be deleted if you want to start from an empty Activity

Comment: So I should just add recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.layout.myRVid); @MikeM.

Comment: OK, you're good. Just make sure your `RecyclerView` is in your `Activity`'s layout somewhere, and `recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RViewId);` in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Such as, under where I add my action bar? @MikeM.

Comment: Yep, that'll work. I've no idea what the tutorial you're watching is doing, but it seems that they just have the `RecyclerView` in a `Fragment`. As I said, if you don't wanna mess with `Fragment`s right now, you don't need to. You'll just have to watch out for where they're using `Fragment` methods, and put the relevant code in the right spots in the `Activity` instead.

Comment: Like so? I added an edit and if I am going to use methods with the RecyclerView where would I put them? @MikeM. sorry I'm a newbie, thank you.

Comment: Yes, that will initialize `recyclerView`. Any other method calls on `recyclerView` - like to set the `LayoutManager` and `Adapter` - can go after that line.

Answer (score 1):

hi @patrick your missing layout manager and data source passing in adapter
here is code snippet that help you to solve your confusion:

oncreate method:
    recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

```
        recyclerAdapter=new RecyclerAdapter(Activity.this,Datasource);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Activity.this));
```

class for Adapter and view holder:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {


private final ArrayList<datasourcemodel> ngoDatas;
private final LayoutInflater inflater;

Context context;

RecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<datasourcemodel> datasource) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.datasource = datasource;
    this.context = context;

}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);  // list base design
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.title.setText();
    holder.desc.setText();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return datasource.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView title, desc;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titles);
        desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dec);
    }
}
```

}

replace Datasouce with your

Comment: Hey I just saw your post and might try it out I just created a RecyclerView and was having trouble I just posted the code. Do you mind giving it a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38471697/recyclerview-not-appearing